# Using ListViewItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

```
foreach (string file in files)
{

      string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
      ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
      item.Tag = file;

      lb.Items.Add(item);
}
```

this code gets an error saying ListViewItem does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation. `ListeViewItem` does not take any arguments in its constructor

```
 ListViewItem l = new ListViewItem();
 l.Content = filename;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem.aspx).